# How to regularly aggregate data from a Mysql DB on AWS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I feed a database (MySQL Aurora RDS on AWS) with a AWS lambda that receive messages and that send it to RDS.

I want also to compute aggregations, to have in my database, a table with the report of each day.

I thought that I could use also a lambda to compute this aggregations, that I would schedule every day. But while both my number of lines in my DB  and my number of aggregations increase, the time to compute those aggregations is to long for a lambda.

Do you know another way to compute such aggregation ? Like a scheduled query in the database ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the MySQL Event Scheduler to trigger an event that runs your aggregations in the db instead of doing it with a lambda.

https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-events/

If you run into issues with access rights, have a look here: [Creating MySQL Events in Amazon RDS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940910/creating-mysql-events-in-amazon-rds)